# How to log port assignments and opening and closing?

Tags: cron, systemd

I am trying to find a good/easy way to log ports assignments and opening and closing them in linux. It should log at least every 10 seconds. (So crontab is not a good option=minumum interval is 1 minute)

Until now the best option I could come up with is trying to use systemd timers to start this

```
ss -aenp &>> /var/log/sslog-`date +%F`.log
```

Or for transmission:

```
systemd-run --on-calendar="*-*-* *:*:*/6" ss -aenp | grep transmi &>> /var/log/sslog-`date +%F`.log
```

But it is not working

```
root@localhost:~# systemd-run --on-calendar="*-*-* *:*:1/6" ss -aenp | grep transmi &>> /var/log/ss-`date +%F`.log
Running timer as unit: run-r4f7f393ed93d4b7ca0e5097ebfa679ec.timer
Will run service as unit: run-r4f7f393ed93d4b7ca0e5097ebfa679ec.service
root@localhost:~# updatedb
root@localhost:~# locate run-r4f7f393ed93d4b7ca0e5097ebfa679ec.timer
root@localhost:~# locate run-r4f7f393ed93d4b7ca0e5097ebfa679ec.service
root@localhost:~# 
root@localhost:~# ls -al /var/log/ss-*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Apr 30 15:45 /var/log/ss-2020-04-30.log
root@localhost:~#
```

The log remains empty and the created timer files cannot be found.

What could have went wrong?

Comment: You could put whatever command it is that you are doing into a `while` loop with a `sleep` statement in a script that runs every 10 seconds:  `while true; do ss -aenp &>> /var/log/sslog-$(date +%F).log; sleep 10; done`  Also, try to avoid backticks ``` and instead use `$( )`

Comment: @Terrance This is actually sufficient for my current need, thanks. But I will leave the question open, because I think it is interesting. And I don't understand what happens with systemd-run. BTW centos 8 (and debian 10) have the same behaviour.